# How to properly convert Bitbucket post-commit Hook shell script to Powershell Script?

Tags: git, shell, powershell

I am trying to setup Post-commit hook for Bitbucket to trigger Teamcity if there is any change in my repo.

Following is the shell script for it:

```
SERVER=https://buildserver-url
USER=buildserver-user
PASS="<password>"

LOCATOR=$1

# The following is one-line:
(sleep 10;  curl --user $USER:$PASS -X POST "$SERVER/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=$LOCATOR" -o /dev/null) >/dev/null 2>&1 <&1 &

exit 0
```

But, I am working on a Windows environment and need this script in Powershell, I tried to convert it to Powershell but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$SERVER=https://buildserver-url
$USER=buildserver-user
$PASS="<password>"

$LOCATOR=%1%

# The following is one-line:
(sleep 10;  curl --user $USER:$PASS -X POST "$SERVER/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=$LOCATOR" -o /dev/null) >/dev/null 2>&1 <&1 &

exit 0
```

I'm not so much familiar with Powershell scripting. Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: Why? A bash script would run perfectly in a Git for Windows bash environment.

Comment: We are actually writing a generalized Powershell script for multiple repositories.

Comment: And you cannot write that generalized script in bash?

Comment: Bitbucket is installed in a Windows server and this script here is for Linux based servers: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+VCS+Post-Commit+Hooks+for+TeamCity 
I'm not sure if I can use a bash script.

Comment: Yes, you can. It will be interpreted by the git bash. On Windows.

Comment: I will try, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the same in PowerShell is arguably a bit more complicated.
We need a job to get a [background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720990/background-job-in-powershell) and have to redirect to [Out-Null](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2011/07/12/2nul-in-powershell/).

```
param (
    [string]$locator  = "xyz"
)
$SERVER="https://buildserver-url"
$USER="buildserver-user"
$PASS="<password>"

$scriptBlock = {
    $output = & curl --user "$($USER):$($PASS)" -X POST "$($SERVER)/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/commitHookNotification?locator=$($args[1])" -o Out-Null 2>&1 | Out-Null;
    return $output
}

#Sleep 10
$job = Start-Job -scriptblock $scriptBlock -ArgumentList $locator
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job

exit 0
```

I cannot test this end-to-end, but this should give you a headstart.